# F-string error in python when running on vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I need help in solving this problem. The screenshot below is of the code line which is giving error. It involves f-string and I am using python 3.7.6 base:conda.

[image]

---

This is the error message that I am getting.

[image]

---

This is the interpreter I am using.

[image]

Please help me solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that is the version of python you are using?  Can you check which version visual studio code uses?

Comment: Comment out any line that uses an f-string, and see what `print(sys.version)` outputs when you run the code.

Comment: It outputs 2.7.16 !!!
What is the problem? I set it using vscode to conda environment that is using 3.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this issue was based on a VS Code extension that I was using to run my code. It was 'Code Runner'.

Two things need to be done:

1. Change this in setting.json

```
code-runner.executorMap": {"python":"$pythonPath $fullFileName"}
```

2. Check "run in terminal" in settings for 'code-runner'.

Comment: Thanks!
on a sidenote: now (November 2020) the step 2 is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching virtualenv in VSCode you have to quit from opened terminal (on linux ctrl-d) and launch it again. Interpreter is not going to change without so.

This apply only to VSCode terminal obviously. And I have no idea if this is only on Linux or on other platforms too.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Even i was getting the same issue see the below screenshot and and make some changes in settings.json and launch.json  and then refresh it, everything will be working fine.
[image: settings.json]

[image: Launch.json]

Comment: Images of text are a pretty awful way to present text

Comment: I tried to help him whatever solution worked for me and i think its clear. I  have just shown the picture to represent whole idea